# How to associate coded ui test in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have few points that I couldn't understand for usage of MTM (Microsoft test Manager). I have written some Coded UI test and now I want to run them in MTM by associating them to manual tests in MTM.

I found from documents that MTM has a build mechanism, works per build, however, my tests are not in the project I connected to Server, they are just in my local pc and in a separate solution.

The points I do not understand

When connecting to TFS, MTC does not ask for a branch or solution, you select a TFT server only, that means all tests coming from all solution will appear as candidate tests to associate to my manual tests in MTM?

Since I wrote coded UI tests, they are not bound to a solution, I can run them on a separate executable screen, what should I do about this? Let's say I checked in my tests on TFS and get them from TFS in MTM, this time what I will get build is not the build that will be tested but it will be tested I will run, will that be a problem ?

Another question, I do not have a separate lab environment, I just want to run coded ui scripts on my local pc, what should I do? Should still define- my local PC as a lab environment in order to run automated tests? If so how to do that ?

Msdn pages does not give much documentation on these points, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasim,

In order to associate tests in MTM, You'll have to build the CodedUI .dll in TFS and be able to select the individual build in MTM. Once you do that, MTM will use that .dll to execute.

If you don't have a test lab / environment set up, you get 0 value from doing this. You will not be able to execute locally from MTM based on those automations.

I'm not sure what context your project is in - but depending on your version of TFS etc. I cannot recommend enough abandoning your plan of associating test cases with automation in this way. Instead, I'd attempt to set up UI test execution as part of a CI/CD pipeline. It's much easier, valuable, and supported by new versions of TFS. The lack of documentation on MS's part is purposeful as CodedUI and ad-hoc execution has been dead for 2-3 years.

Comment: See the note recently added to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2017

Comment: I use VS 2017 and TFS:

Comment: I did not undertand your last paragraph well enough.

Comment: Rasim, Adrian's comment says what I mention in my last comment a bit more succinctly: "Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is deprecated."

CI/CD is a whole extra topic. Essentially you'll get more value out of your UI tests if you execute them as part of your build and deploy process. And if you use technology other than CodedUI (which I have enough experience in to know that it's not as good as competitors) you'll face fewer roadblocks and a more active SO community. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ryanman, Thanks for advices. So you mean associate and run automated tests in test manager (or Azure) is not supported anymore, or codedui as a whole not supported aymore ? But still found in VS 2017 and all related documents ?? I didnt know that. Actually I used different tools before (QTP, Ranorex, Test Complete etc) for UI testing and I see codedui is best for winform/asp.Net applications. On the other hand, my new company already has VS licenses, I think think they wont buy another tool for testing,

Comment: And I still want to try it. Anyway, I check-in my tests under with solution and I have been told they converted to a branch and so that it automaticaly built (as I have been told) but still not sure how to associate them ? cant see it in right menu when I click on tests, can you help me for it ?

Comment: Even if I use a pipeline documents says associate the automated test with a test case ? Document says Create a build pipeline for your project, ensuring that it contains the automated test. Please check step 3 and 4 in below page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=vsts In my VS when I right click on a test in Test Explorer, Associate to Test Case option is disabled what should I do for that ?

Comment: I finaly find to click to Associate to a Test Case window, if warns be "You are not authorised to access <TFS server> so after that even if I write a test case, gives no response, what should I do for that ?

Comment: @rasimavci Please read the link in my earlier comment. Coded UI is deprecated but will be supported in the (not yet released) Visual Studio 2019. That will be the last version that supports it.

Comment: OK I see, its realy weird why they wont support it anymore ? Companies buy enterprise license just because of codedui.. and if you say the issue is support team cost for that software , thats something we are very familier with microsof products, I mean no real support expect msdn (since its helpful in some cases)

Comment: Rasim in my experience the other tech that is suggested in that article is better in nearly every way than CodedUI. For testing a desktop app, I'd go with that. For a web app I wouldn't touch CodedUI with a 10 foot pole. Selenium is so, so, so much better.